# noVNC in ubuntu not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

I cloned noVNC to my local vm:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/kanaka/noVNC
```

then I just ran what they said on their README.md

> > Use the launch script to start a mini-webserver and the WebSockets proxy (websockify). The --vnc option is used to specify the location
> >     of a running VNC server:
>
> ./utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5901
>
> Point your browser to the cut-and-paste URL that is output by the
>   launch script. Enter a password if the VNC server has one configured.
>   Hit the Connect button and enjoy!

Which gets me here:

[image]

but when I hit connect, it says Server disconnected(code 1006) and in the server output in the terminal it says ignoring socket not ready.

**Things I have tried:**

```
sudo netstat -lnp --tcp --udp
```

to get the open ports and it shows the 6080 port as listening but it doesnt show 5901 as listening, which I am not sure if its even supposed to as 5091 would be the socket not the port..

Comment: what happened when you ran the vncserver command that I mentioned?

Comment: @MikePennington  think its getting closer as now it says starting handshake, and then it fails. I followed the walkthrough and my vnc server is running and configured just how the walkthrough says. But when I access my ipaddress and port :5901 on the browser nothing happens, I made sure to add rules to the firewall just like tutorial mentioned.. I get a RFB 003.008

Comment: are you using an encrypted connection?  If so, be sure to generate a self-signed ssl certificate and follow other instructions [here](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/wiki/Encrypted-Connections)

Comment: ok thats what it was.. I ended up using x11vnc with no password or anything and it worked, later I have to work on the security. thanks

Comment: @MikePennington hey, quick question is it possible for a user to show his desktop using a vnc server and novnc ? i.e let say when i go to the site i want to click the button and show my screen rather than connecting to the computer where the vnc server is running on.. Sort of  like http://deadsimplescreensharing.com/ ?

Comment: I really don't know enough about that solution to say... perhaps you could ask a separate question and get an answer about that

Comment: @MikePennington sure thing, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not sure if its even supposed to as 5091 would be the socket not the port

I'm assuming you mean 5901, instead of 5091 because TCP/5901 is what VNC uses by default for display number 1.

First, be sure to generate a self-signed ssl certificate and follow other instructions [here](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/wiki/Encrypted-Connections).

Then, you simply need to run the VNC server itself before you start noVNC.  After you've ensured that VNC is installed, run this command in another window before you run `./utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5901`

```
$ nohup vncserver -localhost -depth 24 -geometry 1200x900 :1 &
$ ## Be sure that VNC is running on port 5901...
$ netstat -an | grep 590.
$ ## Now you can launch noVNC
$ ./utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5901
```

I chose 1200x900 and 24 bit color for you, but you can use anything you like...

Use this to stop your VNC server...

```
$ vncserver -kill :1
```